# Azure Cloud Service There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have been getting error: `Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk.`

I know that this is happening because when user comes to my page a zip file for him/her is downloaded and then unzipped. Each zip has around 45 MB and when unzipped around 50 MB. I start getting this error already after a few visits to page (I believe when 1 GB is downloaded) and saved locally to Cloud Service disc

I'm running this as Cloud Service on Azure, Size of the service is Medium:

Local resource = 489 GB
Apps = approx. 1.5 GB

Is there any way I can increase size of my disc so I can save let's say 50 GB ?

**EDIT**

Here is part of code where I get error:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFile(link, HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/ebookDownloads/" + name));


            using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/ebookDownloads/" + name)))
            {
                foreach (var e in zip)
                {
                    e.Extract(folderToCreate, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently); // overwrite == false
                    // var filePath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/ebookDownloads/" + nameOfFolder + "/" + e.FileName);
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ebookDownloads/" + nameOfFolder), e.FileName);
                    listOfLinks.Add(new EbooksHelper { Name = e.FileName, Size = BytesToString(new FileInfo(filePath).Length), Url = "/platinum/DownloadEbook?name=" + e.FileName });
                    var y = e;
                }          
            }
        }
```

Comment: Pay for more storage on Azure perhaps?

Comment: But where can I set size of Cloud service discs ? I know that there is blob storage and table storage, but I haven't managed to  find option to increase local disc size ?

Comment: Where are you saving these files? In local resources? What's the size you have set in the settings?

Comment: I think that the disk space available on the disk that HostingEnvironment is referring to is limited to 1-2GB. You should instead be using Local Storage, I've updated my answer with how to get the path to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use Local Storage Resources, which are added inside your service definition, e.g.:

```
<ServiceDefinition>
  <WebRole name="MyService_WebRole" vmsize="Medium">
    <LocalResources>
      <LocalStorage name="LocalStorageName" sizeInMB="50000" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
    </LocalResources>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

To access your local storage from runtime you would use `RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource(name)` to be able to get a path to the local storage.

```
var localResource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("LocalStorageName");
var rootPath = localResource.RootPath
```

Comment: Is there any additional code needed to manage LocalStorage, I remember using it with worker role and I had this line of code:  `LocalResource localResource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("PicStorage");` Do I have to do it like this with web role also ?

Comment: I've edited my question so you can see my code where problem occurs

Comment: Im having this same problem.  Does this increase the size of the drive the SITEROOT is on?  Because that is what I need.